# Does `Segmentation fault` message come under STDERR?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, stderr

I ran an executable in `bash`

```
./code > log
```

It shows occasional error messages on terminal whereas all printf statements go into log file. I re-run it like below

```
./code >& log
```

Now, the occasional error messages also go into log. But if there is a segmentation fault, it is still shown on terminal. Why? How to make the message `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` go into the log file?

---

user$ bash --version

GNU bash, version 4.2.24(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A segmentation fault is a signal, if you are not catching this then your program will be terminated and your shell will print this to its stderr (rather than your program's stderr).

It is possible for either your program or the shell to take specific actions when this occurs, either by the program catching the signal or your shell trapping the SIGCHILD signal and then checking your child's exit status.

Comment: Thanks! How would I trap it in shell script? I want to run some other commands depending on whether seg-fault has occurred or not. How would one put an `if` condition using this?

Comment: @user13107 `help trap`

Comment: yup. got it. if anyone's interested, here's what i did http://pastebin.com/QyeJYYHC

Comment: I down voted, because you can't catch segfault signal

Comment: The shell `trap` command traps signals sent to the *shell*. So it won't work to catch the one being sent to your program.

Comment: @warl0ck: `anthony@Zia:~$ trap 'echo foo' SIGSEGV`
`anthony@Zia:~$ kill -SEGV $$`
`foo`
`anthony@Zia:~$ ` ... of course, it won't work for OP, because the signal is going to the program, not the shell. (And yes, if this were a real segv instead of one raised by kill trapping it wouldn't be safe, and may not work)

Comment: @warl0ck it is possible to catch a segfault in the same way you catch any signal, however this can lead to undefined behavior, but if you know what you are doing you may be able to at least die in a sensible way. The OP wanted to print to stderr, in this case catching the segfault and printing is safe.

Comment: I corrected the answer to correctly mention trapping SIGCHILD and testing exit code.

Comment: @warl0ck: you can, it's just a very bad idea to do anything in the handler but log and exit. There are some specialized use cases though.

Answer (score 27):

The “segmentation fault” message is printed to stderr, but it's the shell's standard error, not the program's standard error. The shell prints this message when it detects that the program has terminated due to a signal.

You can silence the message by redirecting stderr around the part of the shell script that runs the program:

```
{ ./code; } >&log
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, this silences the error, but doesn't capture the Segmentation Fault message.

Comment: @BenAveling This puts the “Segmentation fault” message in the file `log`, which is what the question asked for. What else are you expecting?

Comment: PEBKAC at my end - instead of piping to a file, I was trying to capture the Seg fault in a variable, which doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> error messages get redirected but if there is a segmentation fault, it is only shown on the terminal. Why?

TL/DR as per Giles: the segmentation fault message isn't coming from the program's `stderr` or `stdout`, so redirecting those has no effect.  The segmentation fault message is generated by the shell that ran the seg faulting child.

What happens behind the scenes is that after the child dies, the shell calls `wait()` (or `waitpid()`) and uses the response from that to determine whether the child process died because it was signaled.

If so, the shell usually prints a message, but not always.

Note that the shell doesn't magically somehow `trap` the signal that kills the child. Only the child can catch the signal, or be killed by the signal. The parent is sent a SIGCHLD when the child dies, but that's a different signal.

As well as printing an error message, or not, the shell sets `$?` to indicate the exit status.

```
$ ./div_by_0
Floating point exception
$ echo $?
136
```

The same applies to div by zero and other signals. See `man 3 wait` for full details.

One consequence of this is that you will only get a message if the child process is the last in a chain of processes.

e.g.

```
$ ./div_by_0
Floating point exception
$ echo | ./div_by_0
Floating point exception
$ ./div_by_0 | wc
0 0 0
```

Capturing the output from a command into file does not prevent the shell from printing a message, as per Giles.

```
$ { ./div_by_0 ; } > log
Floating point exception
$ { ./div_by_0 ; } >& log
$ cat log
Floating point exception
```

However, capturing the output from a command into a variable does prevent the shell from printing a message.

```
$ a=$(./div_by_0)
$ echo $a
$
```

Capturing the output, whether into a variable or a file, does not prevent `$?` being set.

```
$ { ./div_by_0 ; } >& log
$ echo $?
136
$ a=`{ ./div_by_0 ; }`
$ echo $?
136
```

Depending on what you want to do with the error message, the above may already meet your needs, or you may want to check `$?` after you call your program.

You can also use `trap ERR` to catch the error, and then invoke behaviour to check if `$?` matches SIGSEGV or SIGFPE or whatever.

e.g.

```
$ trap 'exit_code=$?; echo "exit code: $exit_code"; if [[ $exit_code -eq 139 ]]; then echo "segfault"; fi ; if [[ $exit_code -eq 136 ]] ; then echo "div by 0"; fi ;' ERR
$ ./div_by_0
Floating point exception
exit code: 136
div by 0
```

Note, if you `trap` on `SIGCHLD`, your trap code will be invoked before `$?` is set, which is unlikely to be what you want. The faulting command will appear to have returned '$?' = 0, while the following command will appear to have returned a non-zero `$?`

e.g.

```
$ ./div_by_0
exit code: 0
Floating point exception
$ ./div_by_1
exit code: 136      <-- this is $? from div_by_0, not from div_by_1
div by 0
```